# How can I set characters like "{" in urls?

Tags: rest-assured

I need to pass the following URL:

> https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"hostname":{"operation":"hostnameTest"}}}

I tried by different ways, but it doesn't work, this is part of my code:

```
System.out.println(
                given().
                 when().get("https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={\"virtualGuests\":{\"hostname\":{\"operation\":\"hostnameTest\"}}}").asString());

    }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of path parameters. Expected 1, was 0. Undefined path parameters are: "virtualGuests":{"hostname":{"operation":"hostnameTest".
```

According to the exception, I think I should need to use path parameters, I tried with that but I didn't have success.

Also, I tried to replace **{** with character escape code **%7B**.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Sebastian and Robert!

I didn't have success using the encodeURI, however I used **queryParam** and it works

```
given().
                        queryParam("objectFilter", "{\"virtualGuests\":{\"hostname\":{\"operation\":\"hostnameTest\"}}}").
                 when().get("/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests")
                .then().assertThat().body("id", hasItem(1111111));
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this:

```
encodeURI('{"virtualGuests":{"hostname":{"operation":"hostnameTest"}}}')
```

And it gives me:

```
"%7B%22virtualGuests%22:%7B%22hostname%22:%7B%22operation%22:%22hostnameTest%22%7D%7D%7D"
```